# Creating tables with fields from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to create a table that stores values from two different tables;

> From table 1: cust_id (varchar2), invoice_amt (float)
>
> From table 2: cust_id (from table 1), payment_date

My table should have 3 fields:

```
cust_id, invoice_amt, payment_date
```

I tried the following, which is obviously wrong.

```
create table temp1 as (
    select table_1.cust_id, table_1.invoice_amt, table_2.payment_date
      from table_1@dblink, table_2@dblink)
```

Your valuable suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: Hello experts, thanks for your inputs. I've got the table creation going, but my problem is, my table has over 7 million records plus its trying to access records over a dblink. Is there anyway I can speed up the query ? I'm a complete novice, so some detailed help will be great.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create table temp1 as (
    select 
        table_1.cust_id,
        table_1.invoice_amt,
        table_2.payment_date 
    from 
        table_1@dblink, 
        table_2@dblink 
    where 
        table_1.cust_id = table_2.cust_id
    )
```

I'm no oracle guy, but that should do what you want (untested, though).

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
create table temp1 as ( 
    select t1.cust_id, t1.invoice_amt, t2.payment_date 
      from table_1@dblink t1, table_2@dblink t2 
     where t1.cust_id=t2.cust_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're going to use it for, but I'd be sorely tempted to use a view instead of a table:

```
create view temp1(cust_id, invoice_amt, payment_date) as
    select t1.cust_id, t1.invoice_amt, t2.payment_date 
      from table_1@dblink as t1 inner join table_2@dblink as t2
           on t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id
```

The advantage is it always contains the values from the current versions of table_1 and table_2.  The disadvantage is that you cannot edit the view (or, if you can, your edits affect the underlying tables as well as the view).

Comment: The disadvantage is also that you have to pull data over DB link for every query to that view.