# Creating table with fields from 3 different tables Error

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, create-table

i am trying to create a table that is a combination of 3 other tables (but need to join 4 becuase of relations). I was following the post from here:

[Creating tables with fields from 2 different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163082/creating-tables-with-fields-from-2-different-tables)

When i run the query without `CREATE TABLE Customer_Information AS` I dont get any errors and shows me the table. But when i run it with `CREATE` i get this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Information AS (
SELECT DimServere.Servernavn, DimServere.Serverstatus,
       DimKunder.Ministerium, DimKunder.MinisteriumFuldeNavn, DimKunder.RapporteringsKunde, 
       IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Release_, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Level_, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Edition_, 
       IderaPatchAnalyzer.Build, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Updates_Available, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Supported_, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Support_Status

FROM IderaPatchAnalyzer 
        JOIN DimServere
            ON IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse = DimServere.TcpIpAddress
        JOIN FactSystemServereKunder
            ON DimServere.Servernavn = FactSystemServereKunder.Servernavn
        JOIN DimKunder
            On FactSystemServereKunder.KundeID = DimKunder.KundeID
        WHERE DimServere.Serverstatus != 'Disposed/Retired'
        );
```

Also in the table `IderaPatchAnalyzer`, when i do a simple `SELECT * FROM IderaPatchAnalyzer` i get 190 rows. But when i run the joined table, shown above i get 437 rows. My goal is to attach information to those 190 rows. I dont understand why the table gets larger.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think, you can initialize Table that way.
You can use:

```
Select * Into #(tableName)From X where X = Y
```

But then you will need to Drop that Table

```
Drop Table #(tableName)
```

Also important thing is that, it will say it dont know that table but you can use it without a problem.

Your code will then look like:

```
SELECT DimServere.Servernavn, DimServere.Serverstatus,
       DimKunder.Ministerium, DimKunder.MinisteriumFuldeNavn, DimKunder.RapporteringsKunde, 
       IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Release_, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Level_, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Edition_, 
       IderaPatchAnalyzer.Build, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Updates_Available, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Supported_, IderaPatchAnalyzer.Support_Status
INTO #Customer_Information 
FROM IderaPatchAnalyzer 
        JOIN DimServere
            ON IderaPatchAnalyzer.IP_Adresse = DimServere.TcpIpAddress
        JOIN FactSystemServereKunder
            ON DimServere.Servernavn = FactSystemServereKunder.Servernavn
        JOIN DimKunder
            On FactSystemServereKunder.KundeID = DimKunder.KundeID
        WHERE DimServere.Serverstatus != 'Disposed/Retired'

        --Your Code

        DROP TABLE #Customer_Information
```

For your next problem. You have multiple references to 1 item. It should be solved when you add more Conditions to `JOIN` / `WHERE`

Comment: I tested what you said and instead of #Customer_Information, just typed Customer_Information, and actually created a table with those information. I could then alter the table and add IP_Adresse primay key. Is this a accepted method? or is it a big no go?